# Can someone explain what is a HelperClass and what does in Java or in C++?

Tags: java, c++

I want to know what the HelperClass used for. Can someone please explain it with examples?

Thank You

Comment: C doesn't have classes (at least, as a built-in language construct), so it makes little sense to talk about "helper classes" there.

Comment: @MatteoItalia just edited the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A helper class (in Java, at least) is usually just a static utility class with a variety of methods. In general, a single helper class deals with related functionality, like Apache Commons' StringUtils class, that has a bunch if static methods that operate on strings.

In Java, these types of classes often exist to wrap up functionality that either cannot (for example, the String class is final, so additional functionality can't be added) or should not be addedto the class itself.

In a nutshell, however, a helper class is a class that helps, by providing general or specific functionality in a generic, reusable, encapsulated way.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually used to preserve the cohesion of a class (in Java). Useful methods that don't really belong in any of the classes context can be put in a helper class (static of course) so you can call them.

Comment: A good example is the Math class.  Lots of classes need access to the function within it so they end up calling the Math class's static methods.

Answer (score 0):

They are usually static methods. They dont belong to a class or a context of the class, but instead using a class, you can provide some sort of functionality with a helper class/ static classes.

Answer (score 0):

Informal way of referring to [Utility Class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_class)